# selecting the ID that fulfils multiple clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, select

It's hard to put in correctly, but I'm using MySQL and I need to select one id, let's call it parent_id which has to meet child_id values in multiple rows.

For example:

```
   +-----------+----------+
   | parent_id | child_id |
   +-----------+----------+
   |     1     |    10    |
   +-----------+----------+
   |     2     |    11    |
   +-----------+----------+
   |     2     |    12    |
   +-----------+----------+
   |     3     |    13    |
   +-----------+----------+
   |     4     |    11    |
   +-----------+----------+
   |     5     |    12    |
   +-----------+----------+
```

Now if I pass child_id parameters 11 and 12, I have to get parent_id 2 back, but if I pass 10 and 11, I have to get nothing back. Also, if I pass 11, I have to receive 4. And if I pass 13, I have to receive 3 back.

How do I go about this? I tried counting the parent_id's and using HAVING clause, also using GROUP BY clause, but nothing I try meets all of my requirements.

**EDIT:**

Example Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abbc4/5

**EDIT2:**

*Expected results:*

Passed parameters: 11, 12
Received result: 2

Passed parameters: 11
Received result: 4

Passed parameters: 13
Received result: 3

Passed parameters: 12, 13
Received result NULL

**EDIT3:**

Updated the spec. See here also: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f750/1

Comment: Wow! Not even Google translate could help me understand this.

Comment: That's not the fault of the OP. It's quite understandable: He wants to create a query, that returns the `parent_id` only if all corresponding `child_id`s have been specified and no `child_id` has been specified that belongs to a different `parent_id`

Comment: What would you get for `10, 13`. Nothing? Or `1` and `3`? Alternatively: For `11, 12, 13`: Nothing? Or `2` and `3`?

Comment: @donkapone Now, according to your latest update, `child_id in (11,12)` should return `null`. Please also update your description *Now if I pass child_id parameters 11 and 12, I have to get parent_id 2* and also update *Passed parameters: 11, 12 Received result: 2*

Comment: But if I pass child_ids 11 and 12, it should still return parent_id 2, but if I only pass 11 as child_id, it should return parent_id 4, and not parent_id 2, because parent_id 2 has more child_ids than just 11. In other words, to get needed parent_id, you have to pass all its children. Not less, not more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statement does what you want. I am not so sure about its performance though...

```
select t.parent_id, t.cnt from
(
    select parent_id, count(*) cnt
    from t 
    WHERE child_id IN (12, 11)
    GROUP BY parent_id
) t
inner join
(
    select parent_id, count(*) cnt
    from t group by parent_id
) s
on t.parent_id = s.parent_id
and t.cnt = s.cnt -- Check that the parent has exactly as many children as
                  -- passed in - and not more. Prevents matching if only part
                  -- of the children of a parent were specified.
and t.cnt = 2 -- Check that all passed in children produced a match on the same
              -- parent. Prevents matching of parents that match only a subset
              -- of the specified children
```

Replace the `2` with the number of specified children in the `IN` list.

Comment: You did wonders here. Unfortunately, I did not write the specification fully correct. I'm going to update the question with the full hoorah.

Comment: I still did a work around in PHP and a couple queries more, since this query, as expected, did not deliver enough performance to the script. Still, good to know it is possible to do it this way as well.

Comment: @donkapone: Make sure you got the right indexes in place. That should speed up the query significantly.

Comment: They're all there. It's still quite fast though - 50ms to look through 20MB large table with 100k rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this more compact version

```
select case
         when min(t.parent_id) = max(t.parent_id) -- parent_ids are the same?
              -- and all children share the same parent?
              and count(t.parent_id) = (
                          select count(parents.parent_id)
                            from t parents
                           where parents.parent_id in
                              (select parent_id
                                 from t 
                                where child_id in (11, 12) -- <= change here
                               )) 
         then t.parent_id
         else null
       end as parent_id
  from t 
 where child_id in (11, 12); -- <= and here
```

I have tested this and works for all your use cases

You can test here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abbc4/183

Answer (score 0):

You have to have two variables for this to work. First one is the comma separated list of your child_ids (`child_list`) and second is the number of the children (the count of children in your child_list) you are searching for (`child_count`).

```
SELECT parent_id,COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE child_id IN (<child_list>) 
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=<child_count>
```

This should give you the desired results.

Comment: I like the elegance of your answer. However, isn't this only working if you already know which parent you are looking for and therefore have the number of its children?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth If I understood the OP correctly his question was "I have the children x,y,z and want to know if they are all related to a common parent". And then you'll know the number of children.

Comment: The OP clearly states in his answer that he wants the matching parent as a return value. So the parent is the expected result and not part of the input.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Correct. And my statement returns the parent_id if all child_ids are related to a common parent. The parent_id is the result, not the input.

Comment: And where is `child_count` coming from? If it is `count(child_list)` your query produces wrong results.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Given the information by OP the results should be ok. It is never mentioned what should happen if there are more children of a parent and you'll only query for a subset of these children.

Comment: Not correct. See the spec in the question: "Passed parameters: 11 Received result: NULL". Your query returns 2.

Comment: The information was there before you even answered... ;-) The original question also contained that info already: "Also, if I pass 11, I have to receive nothing".

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Darn tabs ... I opened the question, searched for some info and then started to comment ... I read the updated question after you pointed it out. Sorry for the mass commenting.